# add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post')); is not uploading the file

Tags: post-thumbnails

So I used the codes below in the functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post'));
set_post_thumbnail_size(100, 75);
```

And then in THE LOOP I called:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

The image has an entry in the database with its url but the file isn't uploaded when I checked in the wp-content/uploads/ directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you adding the image from the featured image in the post edit screen? does the image show in the post edit screen? What does your page source show? what is the process that you are taking to add the image?

Comment: Hi @Jamie!

are you adding the image from the featured image in the post edit screen? -- **Yes**

does the image show in the post edit screen? -- **It doesn't show up there already. Just the icon of a broken link of pic.**

what is the process that you are taking to add the image? --- **I use featured image on the right side and then upload pic and use as featured image.**

File is not uploaded to uploads dir
Post/pic has entry to database.

Comment: Can you see the image in the media gallery?  Has the full-size image been uploaded?